# jQuery image Grid System

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gridview, grid

I have one question about image grid system.

I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPpedQ)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see :

```
<div class="photo-row">
<div class="photo-item">
<!--Posted image here <img src="image/abc.jpg"/>-->
</div>
</div>
```

This DEMO is working fine but. My question is how can I use my grid system like in this css:

```
<div class="photo">

        <div class="photo-row">
            <a href="#"><img src="abc.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="photo-row">
            <a href="#"><img src="abc.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

I created second demo for this: ***second*** **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/QwGPKK)**. In the second demo you can see the grid system not working like first **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPpedQ)**.

Also my jQuery code:

```
(function($,sr){

  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null;
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
  }
  // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');

/* Wait for DOM to be ready */
$(function() {

    // Detect resize event
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        // Set photo image size
        $('.photo-row').each(function () {
            var $pi    = $(this).find('.photo-item'),
                  cWidth = $(this).parent('.photo').width();

            // Generate array containing all image aspect ratios
            var ratios = $pi.map(function () {
                return $(this).find('img').data('org-width') / $(this).find('img').data('org-height');
            }).get();

            // Get sum of widths
            var sumRatios = 0, sumMargins = 0,
          minRatio  = Math.min.apply(Math, ratios);
            for (var i = 0; i < $pi.length; i++) {
                sumRatios += ratios[i]/minRatio;
            };

      $pi.each(function (){
        sumMargins += parseInt($(this).css('margin-left')) + parseInt($(this).css('margin-right'));
      });

            // Calculate dimensions
            $pi.each(function (i) {
                var minWidth = (cWidth - sumMargins)/sumRatios;
                $(this).find('img')
          .height(Math.floor(minWidth/minRatio))
                    .width(Math.floor(minWidth/minRatio) * ratios[i]);
            });
        });
    });
});

/* Wait for images to be loaded */
$(window).load(function () {

    // Store original image dimensions
    $('.photo-item img').each(function () {
      $(this)
        .data('org-width', $(this)[0].naturalWidth)
        .data('org-height', $(this)[0].naturalHeight);
    });

  $(window).resize();
});
```

[image]

Anyone can help me in this regard ? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Wow, you got some cool looking JavaScript/jQuery functions there. I noticed that in the code sample that didn't work you had all <div class="photo-item"> contained within the same <div class="photo-row">. In the sample that worked, each <div class="photo-item"> had its own <div class="photo-row">. So if you can change your code in a way that user posted images have their own <div class="photo-row">, then I guess your code should be working :-)

Comment: I tested your code (not working part) and added by hand individual <div class="photo-row"> to all <div class="photo-item">, and it started to work. The part of your code that adds user loaded images to the first and only <div class="photo-row">, if you can change that then I guess that'll make it work. You JavaScript was so advanced, and at first glance I wasn't able to detect any user loading part. Maybe server side change(?). Good Luck!

Comment: Where i did something wrong ? Why someone given me -vote ?

Comment: I think the second demo might be working. Originally, it didn't but it was updated with individual <div class="photo-row"> for each image; so after an update it looks kind of okay, in my opinion.

Comment: What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @jbutler483 main div is a `.photo` in second [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/QwGPKK) and images in `.photo-row` .Then so if you check first [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPpedQ) then you can see images is in `.photo-item` Hovewer i want to use only `.photo-row` i don't want `.photo-row` inside images in `.photo-item` . My english is not very good i can not say exactly what i want. But i hope you can unserstand me now.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, "what do you want to make?" An image gallery in tile view? A carousel?

Comment: @jbutler483 I want to show pictures only in `.photo-row` div (in the Grid system)  -- Like second [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/QwGPKK)

Comment: @innovation@ So you want a 'vertical gallery', in which all images are the same height? (please don't answer "like demo") - i'm just trying to think of your 'overall wish' for the user - You want them to scroll down, and view images all the same height?

Comment: @jbutler483 I edited my question so there is a picture for what i want to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you'll be creating the HTML dynamically you should remove the `.photo-row` container but keep `.photo-item` like so:

```
        <div class="photo-item">
            <a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="photo-item">
            <a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="photo-item">
            <a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
        </div>
        ...
```

Then what you can do is wrap your elements with `.photo-row` on page load. First starting with various sets of two:

```
var imgGrab  = $('.photo-item'); //photos
var imgLength = imgGrab.length; //number of photos

for ( i=0; i<imgLength; i=i+3 ) {
   imgGrab.eq(i+1).add( imgGrab.eq(i+1) ).add( imgGrab.eq(i+2) ).wrapAll('<div class="photo-row"></div>'); //wrap photos
}
```

Then find the remanding ones and wrap those with `.photo-row` as well:

```
$(".photo-item").each(function(){
   if($(this).parent().is(":not(.photo-row)")){
     $(this).wrap('<div class="photo-row"></div>');
   }
});
```

This will wrap your images dynamically and let the CSS do its job regardless of the number of them:

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYLwRV)

Comment: this amazingly clean and accurate answer. Thank you very much. I am honored to give you points.You really deserve.

Comment: Dear i need help. Can you help me ?