# CSS inner shadow

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with css inner shadow.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jEyXLr)** from codepen.io

So the problem is that inner shadow on the image can not be displayed.You will see if you click on the demo link at the bottom of the image can not be displayed inner shadow.

How can i view inner shadow on the image?

HTML :

```css
body {
  background-color: #323949;
  font-family: 'mstfont' !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.globalHeader {
  z-index: 90;
  background-color: #323949;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3f4858;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}
.globalHeader_in {
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 960px;
  width: 100%!important;
  max-width: 1580px;
  height: 52px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 15px;
  margin: auto;
}
.profil-kapak {
  width: 100%;
  height: 385px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3f4858;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;
}
.image {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 385px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="globalHeader">
  <div class="globalHeader_in">header</div>
</div>
<div class="profil-kapak">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Frozen-Movie-poster-payoff-Wallpaper-HD1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add an inner shadow to an image. Instead what you can do is set the parent `.image` to `positon:relative` and create an overlay set to `position:absolute` that has the box-shadow:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
   <img src="..."></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;    
}
```

(switched to fiddle, im just used to it):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lknr70/)

Comment: i don't want to add another div for shadow. I am asking just how can i show `.profil-kapak` inner shadow on the image

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to say you **CANT**. That cant be done, the only way to do it is like this, or you edit the image in photoshop or something

Comment: that image is user cover photo :) So users do not have to use photoshop to do so.

Comment: yes i checked your answer but this is not solution for me. I  can search another method for that.

Comment: I meant the checkmark underneath the vote. Can i ask why this not a solution?

Comment: I said not a solution for me. Of course, your answer was correct. Not a problem, I will give you points.

Comment: Can i ask you something. Can you check this question for me.  [**CLİCK**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801055/jquery-image-grid-system) from stackoverflow.com

Comment: so you want that image gallery to look like the photo you posted? And you want this done with CSS or Jquery?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the CSS. But jQuery can be a problem.

Comment: I think i understand your issue, you removed a div and now its not working right, correct?

Comment: Yes i want to image gallery like that. But there are eight images Maybe the user can more or less share more photos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68621/discussion-between-jmore009-and-innovation).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-shadow {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img-shadow::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 14px rgba(90,0,90,0.65) inset;
    content: "";
}
.img-shadow>img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<span class="img-shadow">
    <img width=280px; src="http://www.accordionplus.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1_web_mini.jpg">
</span>
```